# Conditional Insert in mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I am really a beginner in mysql. In oracle we can use **triggers** , which can **detect** the insert elements and allows to fully break the insert command if something is wrong. I've found that mysql also supports triggers, but how can we use them for detecting insert parameters and stopping them to be inserted if they don't satisfy rules.

```
e.g. INSERT INTO accounts (userId, balance) VALUES ('12','450'); // Valid
     INSERT INTO accounts (userId, balance) VALUES ('12','-574'); // Invalid

if(balance<0){
  Do not insert;
}
else{
   Insert;
}
```

**NOTE**: I'm dealing with **concurrent transactions**, so **STRICTLY need triggers**, i.e. lowest level error detection so that no one can hack.
Any help will be appreciated. Thanks,

Comment: Where's the problem, it's just about how you describe it in PHP as well. You check for the `$balance` variable for negativity, and act appropriately.

Comment: Will you do this in php script or pure mysql?

Comment: I'm dealing with concurrent transactions, so STRICTLY need trigger, i.e. lowest level error detection so that no one can hack.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Or use an BEFORE INSERT trigger

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE TRIGGER au_a_each BEFORE INSERT ON accounts FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
IF new.balance > 0 THEN
  BEGIN
    INSERT INTO b (id,balance) VALUES (new.id, new.balance);
  END 
END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

More info in the mysql documentation : http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-trigger.html

PS: Programming  lesson number 1(One with capital "o") - Befriend whatever programming/scripting language's documentation

Answer (score 1):

You may use INSERT IGNORE and set ALTER TABLE field constraints in mysql

Comment: As I said I'm recently switched to mysql, please provide a decent example.

Comment: I assume you have bulk data in a form of INSERT INTO statements. You can set field attribute UNSIGNED for the balance field while creating the table. Then change your slq statements to INSERT IGNORE INTO. Data where balance field values are greater or equal to zero will be inserted. The others will not give error, but also not inserted i.e. they will be ignored .